# Shader for orthographic projection of the texture on the model

Tags: uv, shaders, shader-nodes, orthographic, project

I recently started looking for a shader for orthographic projection of a texture onto a model from the camera. I needed to bake a projected texture. Found an example with perspective projection and OSL rays. However, I don't understand how to rewrite this for the orthographic case. I see in the code finding the camera normals, but next for me is shader magic. Could someone help to do this with the orthographic case?
[image: shader]
[image]

Update:
Try to reproduce answer
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the bake you want to obtain. But why not simply : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUxeD.jpg

Comment: @lemon could you upload the blender file?

Comment: Here you are, Denis, [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=e93xBBZ8" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/e93xBBZ8/)

Comment: @lemon https://ibb.co/d580wP1 - your case , https://ibb.co/XSCx9dy - goal. In your implementation, the texture is also drawn on those parts that are not visible from the camera. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @lemon ... hope I haven't stepped on your toes.. will back out if you put in your own answer.

Comment: @RobinBetts, no pb at all. You're the Betts, you know ; )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to bake an ortho projection from the camera

[image]

.. with the backfacing shading-points mixed to another colour:

[image]

Here, the mix is plugged straight into the Material Output, and 'Emission' is baked.

It's all a bit confusing while you're setting it up, because 'Camera Space' in your node tree includes the camera space of the viewports. That means you're working blind; you can't see round the back of your object until the bake is made and assigned.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your solution. However, for some reason I got a darkened result. Could you please attach the file or look at the file that I will attach now when I change the question?

Comment: @denisbaic, try to adjust your bake settings... "diffuse" and only "color"

Comment: @lemon it worked! Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @denisbaic, please accept Robin's answer.

Comment: Hi, @denisbaic thanks! My mix was stuck straight into the material output without an explicit shader, because I didn't know how you wanted to use your texture, and I baked 'Emisson'. Same difference.. I should have included that in the illustration.